# Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions with react version 16.4

Tags: reactjs

I get this error while trying to build npm run watch -

Here is my webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
          {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
                 presets: ['react']
                }
            }
          ]

        }
      ]
    },

};
module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "flask-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a simple flast react integration app.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -p --progress --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-build": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "webpack": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Creating a Full-Stack Python Application with NPM, React.js and Webpack</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" />
    <script src="dist/bundle.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from “react”;
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <p> Hello React!</p>;
  }
}
```

index.jsx

```
// index.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("content"));
```